# How to Delete Completely Empty Columns in Excel on a Mac

Tags: microsoft-excel, sorting

This is based on the MAC version of Excel 2017.

I have an excel spreadsheet with many columns. Each column has a title. 
I would like to know how to delete all the completely blank columns in this spreadsheet.

**My definition of Blank Columns:** columns that don't have any other entries in them except for the title

Answer (score 0):

This works on Windows, try it on your MAC:

```
Sub KolumnKiller()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        N = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        For i = N To 1 Step -1
            If .CountA(Columns(i)) < 2 Then Cells(1, i).EntireColumn.Delete
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```